# Trying to dynamically allocate an array inside an element of a vector of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a vector of point type( point is a structure which contains 2 ints and a pointer to int, s) and I m trying to dynamically allocate memory for the s array( malloc / new) and add two values to it but it gives me seg fault. I don t know if I m allowed to do this inside a vector element. Thank you in advance.

```
struct point{
    int x, y;
    int *s;
};

int main(void){

    int n, val1, val2, val3, val4, i;
    vector<point> v;

    v.resize(2);
    cin >> n;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> val1 >> val2 >> val3 >> val4;
        v[i - 1].x = val1;
        v[i - 1].y = val2;
        v[i - 1].s = new int[2]; // here i think is the problem.
        //v[i - 1].s = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        v[i - 1].s[0] = val3;
        v[i - 1].s[1] = val4;
    }
    for(i = 0; i <= v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].x << " " << v[i].y << " " << v[i - 1].s[0] << " " << v[i - 1].s[1] ;
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<int> s;` instead? Also, what happens if `n` is larger than what you've made place for in `v`? And why `i - 1` instead of starting the loop at `0`?

Comment: Are there always 2 integers in `s`? If so maybe a `std::array<int,2>` is more appropriate.

Comment: `i <= v.size()` looks like a bug. `v[v.size()]` is one element past the end of the vector. `v[i - 1]` is also a bug when `i` is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't `resize()` the `vector` to `n`. You have a fixed value of `2`. This will make the program have undefined behavior as soon as someone enters something larger than `2` in `std::cin >> n`.
- The second loop `for(i = 0; i <= v.size(); i++)` will make the program access `v[v.size()]` which is out-of-bounds so your program has undefined behavior.
- The loop `for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)` isn't wrong since you compensate with `i - 1` inside the loop, but it's unnecessary. Do `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)` or use a range based for-loop (as I'll show below).
- Don't use `new` for `s`. Either use a fixed size `std::array<int, 2>` or a `std::vector<int>` that you can resize.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct point {
    int x, y;
    std::vector<int> s; // use a vector instead of a raw pointer
};

int main() {   // not main(void)
    int n, val1, val2, val3, val4;
    std::vector<point> v;

    if(!(std::cin >> n)) return 1; // extraction may fail

    v.resize(n); // resize it appropriately

    // you can access the `point`s in the vector using a range based for-loop:
    for(point& p : v) {
        if(std::cin >> val1 >> val2 >> val3 >> val4) { // check if extraction succeeded
            p.x = val1;
            p.y = val2;
            p.s.resize(2);
            p.s[0] = val3;
            p.s[1] = val4;
        } // else /* break, return 1, ... something */
    }

    // You can also access the elements like this, but pay attention
    // to the condition: i < v.size()
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << v[i].x << ' ' << v[i].y << ' '
                  << v[i].s[0] << ' ' << v[i].s[1] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Another option is to *not* `resize()` `v` at all and just use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to add new `point`s to it. Note how the inner `vector`, `s`, gets appropriately sized automatically:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(std::cin >> val1 >> val2 >> val3 >> val4) {
            v.emplace_back(point{val1, val2, {val3, val4}});
        } else
            break;
    }
```

Also note that accessing `v.s[0]` and `v.s[1]` without checking that it actually has `2` elements is a bit risky, but if you *know* that's always the case after your initial loop, it should be fine.

Comment: At first i used only 2 elements to insert in the vector( from here v.resize(2) ) and then when i switched to n, i forgot to change it. I really understood both of your solutions, indeed it s way better to use vector<int> s instead of int *s, but I m still used to the C way of doing things.

Comment: @StefanSs Yeah, that part took me a while too when going from C to C++ - but you're on the right track since you already used a `vector` for `v` - and the range based for-loops are really neat. One rarely makes a mistake when having to go through all elements in a loop when using them.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    v[i - 1].s = new int[2]; // here i think is the problem.
    v[i - 1].s[0] = val3;
    v[i - 1].s[1] = val4;
```

Is not **the** problem. The fact that `s` is a member of an element in a vector is not really relavant. The above is as correct as this:

```
int* s;
s = new int[2]; // here i think is the problem.
s[0] = val3;
s[1] = val4;
```

It is **a** problem, because it is not clear why you want to use a manually allocated array here. I am always a bit puzzled when I see `std::vector` and `new int[2]` in the same code. From a vector you get all you can get from a dynamically allocated array and more. Anyhow the problem causing the segfault is elsewhere...

```
v.resize(2);
cin >> n;
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    cin >> val1 >> val2 >> val3 >> val4;
    v[i - 1].x = val1;
    ....
```

`v` has 2 elements. Nowhere in your code the number of elements changes. When the user enters anything bigger than 2 for `n` you will access the vector out of bounds. Out of bounds access is undefined behavior. Anything could happen when you run the code.

Also your last loop is wrong. The last valid index is `v.size()-1`. It is common to use half open intervals, ie the start is included, end not:

```
 for(i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
         //   ^^ not <= !!!
```

Comment: I m using new because I m used to C, where you have to dynamically allocate arrays with malloc, realloc, calloc. Now i m starting to understand vectors. Indeed I made some huge mistakes. The "<= v.size()" and <<v[i - 1].s[0] ( i copy and pasted it without realizing that is i - 1 instead of i.

Comment: @StefanSs its rather rare in modern C++ that you have to use `new`. Containers and smart pointers cover most cases of dynamic allocation